# Azure Cosmos DB Query: How to concatenate arrays across docs?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Documents in my CosmosDB database all have an array element like so:

```
{
    id: 1,
    list: [1, 2, 3]
},
{
    id: 2,
    list: [2, 3, 4]
},
...
```

I want a query that concatenates the array "list" across all documents (ideally, I'd like a UNIQUE concatenation but I can start with all of them).

The result I want is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

or even better:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This "feels" like an aggregate but I can't seem to get my head around it. Any ideas?

I know I can load each document in turn and iterate. I was hoping to do this with a query and avoid the expense of loading every document in turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using SQL query**

You can select individual values from within array by joining and merge the resulting values back into single array by using the `value` keyword:

```
SELECT value i
FROM c
join i in c.list
```

Note that this returns all values in a single array but unfortunately including duplicates.

To my knowledge there is currently no server-side distinct capability. But there is a request of ["Provide support for DISTINCT"](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct) with 1k+ votes, so I believe it will be possible at some point in the future. If this is something you care about, then go and upvote.

**Using SP**

Alternative way of getting unique list made on server-side would be to use Stored Procedures within you documentDB collection:

```
function GetUniqueItems() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT value i FROM c join i in c.list',
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var uniqueArray = feed
                .filter(function(item, pos) { return feed.indexOf(item) == pos;});
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(uniqueArray);
        });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

You can read more how to utilize DocumentDB serverside programming from 
["Azure Cosmos DB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming).

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'Distinct', it is supported now:

```
SELECT distinct value i FROM c join i in c.list
```

Results in: **[1, 2, 3, 4]**